# GAE Java Objectify Can't find a parent

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I'm starting in Java/Objectify and i'm encountering a problem.

*(A colleague just post my question in french before because he didn't know the rules and I didn't have an account.)*

To explain, I have 3 classes what are working as this:
A Server have a Site parent what have a Country parent.

I worked on my classes Site and Country without any problem, i can keep easily the data of my Country from a Site. Example:

```
Site site = ofy().load().type(Site.class).filter("name", "Angers").first().now();
System.out.println(ofy().load().key(site.getCountry()).now().getName());
```

What returns: **"France"**

But, when I try to keep a Site from a Server as the same way:

```
System.out.println("- Server->Site - "+ofy().load().key(a.getSite()).now().getName());
```

I got an ***java.lang.NullPointerException***

By the way, when I do only a getSite(), the return is also null:

```
Site x=ofy().load().key(a.getSite()).now();
if(x==null)
System.out.println("null");
else
System.out.println("NOT null");
```

Result: **null**

However, I'm doing some tests in my constructor to verify if the key is well saved:

```
System.out.println(serverSite.toString()+"="+this.site.toString());
```

What returns **Key(Site(4754288278503424))=Key(Site(4754288278503424))**

This is another test what i'm doing just after the Key creation in the program

```
List<Site> yy=ofy().load().type(Site.class).filter("name","Dijon").list();
cleSitekey = Key.create(Site.class, yy.get(0).getId());
System.out.println("SITE KEY: "+cleSiteid.toString());
List<Site> l=ofy().load().type(Site.class).filter("name",yy.get(0).getName()).list();       
for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++){
Key<Site> keysiteserv= Key.create(Site.class, l.get(i).getId());
System.out.println("index " + i + " = " + l.get(i).getName()+" - "+ l.get(i).getId());
System.out.println(cleSitekey.toString());
System.out.println(cleSitekey.compareTo(keysiteserv));
}
```

What returns goodly 0 to precise that the keys have the same value:

**Élément à l'index 0 = Dijon - 4754288278503424**

**Key(Site(4754288278503424))**

**0**

Only having an experience on relational databases, I dont know if I don't get the Keys concept and if I'm misunderstanding it or if I just dont get how to do.

My classes Site and Server:

```
@Entity
@Index 
public class Site {
@Id Long idSite; 
private String name;
@Parent Key<Country> country; 

private Site(){}

public Site(String siteName, Key<Country> siteCountry){
if(siteCountry!=null){
List<Site> l=ofy().load().type(Site.class).filter("name",siteName).ancestor(siteCountry).list();

if(l.size()==0){
System.out.println("Object created.");
this.name=siteName;
this.country=siteCountry;
ofy().save().entity(this).now();
}
else
{
System.out.println("Object creation stopped, it already exists.");
}
}
}
//getters+setters etc
}
```

.

```
@Entity
@Index 
public class Server {

@Id Long idServer;
private String hostname;
private String ip;
private int status;
private String statusDate; 
private String lastTimeUp; 
@Parent Key<Site> site;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Server(){}

public Server(String serverHostName,  String serverIp, int serverStatus, String serverStatusDate, String serverLastTimeUp, Key<Site> serverSite){
if(serverSite!=null){

List<Server> l=ofy().load().type(Server.class).filter("hostname",serverHostName).filter("ip",serverIp).ancestor(serverSite).list();     
System.out.println("list ok.");
if(l.size()==0){
this.hostname = serverHostName;
this.ip = serverIp;
this.status = serverStatus;
this.statusDate = serverStatusDate;
this.lastTimeUp = serverLastTimeUp;
this.site = serverSite;
System.out.println("Test start");
System.out.println(serverHostName+"="+this.hostname);
System.out.println(serverIp+"="+this.ip);
System.out.println(serverStatus+"="+this.status);
System.out.println(serverLastTimeUp+"="+this.lastTimeUp);
System.out.println(serverSite.toString()+"="+this.site.toString());
System.out.println("Test end");
try{
ofy().save().entity(this).now();
System.out.println("Object created.");
}
catch(Exception ex){
System.out.println("Saving interrupted.");
System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());   
}   
}
else
{
System.out.println("Object creation stopped, it already exists.");
}
}
}
//getters/setters/etc
}
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are constructing the keys does not look right to me. As per documentation if an entity has a parent, then you have to use the Key.create(parent, class, id) method overload that has an overload for parent.
For example, to create a key for Server object which has Site as parent you have to do the following:

// Note: site is the parent

`Key<Server> serverKey = Key.create(site, Server.class, server.getId());`

Comment: Oh thanks I didn't understand that! I try it for Server and the Site Key is 


Key<?>(Country(6020925673701376)/Site(4754288278503424))

and not 

Key<?>(Site(4754288278503424)) 

as i was doing. 
Thanks a lot =)

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help. Since you're a beginner I would recommend you first read the Google App Engine documentation on the Datastore, then having done that read the excellent Objectify documentation and everything will suddenly make sense. :)